# socket_read make response nameserver readable

Tags: php, hex, ascii

How can i make a response from a nameserver readable?

if my response is:
`0x01, 0x01, 0x85, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x0e, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x67, 0x6f, 0x6f, 
0x67, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x02, 0x6e, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x00, 
0xff, 0x00, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x04, 0xad, 
0xc2, 0x20, 0x77, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x04, 0xad, 
0xc2, 0x20, 0x7f, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x04, 0xad, 
0xc2, 0x20, 0x78, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x03, 
0x6e, 0x73, 0x33, 0x06, 0x67, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x67, 
0x6c, 0x65, 0x03, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x00, 0xc0, 
0x0c, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 
0x2c, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x76, 0x3d, 0x73, 0x70, 
0x66, 0x31, 0x20, 0x2d, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0xc0, 
0x0c, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 
0x58, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x05, 0x61, 0x73, 
0x70, 0x6d, 0x78, 0x01, 0x6c, 0xc0, 0x5b, 0xc0, 
0x0c, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 
0x58, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x04, 0x61, 0x6c, 
0x74, 0x32, 0xc0, 0x8d, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x06, 
0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x00, 0x22, 
0xc0, 0x57, 0x09, 0x64, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x2d, 0x61, 
0x64, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x6e, 0xc0, 0x5b, 0x00, 0x16, 
0xf7, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x03, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x3c, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x01, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x58, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x32, 
0x04, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x74, 0x34, 0xc0, 0x8d, 0xc0, 
0x0c, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 0x46, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x03, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x32, 0xc0, 
0x5b, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 
0x05, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x03, 0x6e, 0x73, 
0x34, 0xc0, 0x5b, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x58, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 
0x28, 0x04, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x74, 0x33, 0xc0, 0x8d, 
0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x05, 
0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x03, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x31, 
0xc0, 0x5b, 0xc0, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x01, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x58, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x14, 
0x04, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x74, 0x31, 0xc0, 0x8d`

then this is my ascii output
`.............google.nl..............,.... w.........,.... ..........,.... x........F....ns3.google.com..........,...v=spf1 -all.........X...
.aspmx.l.[.........X.....alt2...........<.".W.dns-admin.[...
...............<.........X...2.alt4..........F....ns2.[........F....ns4.[.........X...(.alt3..........F....ns1.[.........X.....alt1..`

This is the info I get back from one of the google nameservers. How can I make it readable with php?

Comment: It looks like you are implementing your own DNS parser (why...?), It is all documented in RFC1035: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

Comment: What do you mean by readable  ...

Comment: @Baba when i view the packet in wireshark i can see name, type, ttl, class etc. which wireshark has taken from the hex data. that is what i want to do too but i have no idea how to say this is the name or this is the type.